# VBA HTML : Downloading data from hidden IE window

Tags: html, vba, internet-explorer, excel

I'm trying to navigate to [Photovoltaic Geographical Information System - Interactive Maps](http://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvgis/apps4/pvest.php)(done), fill the fields I need (done), press **Caluclate** with **Web page** as output option(done).

Then a window with data pops up. I want to dowload the content of a data table to my worksheet and close both windows.
I'm able to do this only with `InternetExplorer.visible = True` (using a loop through `ShellWindows`, there are 2 windows => correct, but I don't want windows to be visible). However when the `InternetExplorer.visible = False` there is only the main window, not the popup => incorrect.

***My question is:*** How can I point to the **hidden popup window** and download the data from it? Probably using something different than *ShellWindows*.

**The code**

```
Sub PVGISDownload()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim shellWins As New ShellWindows

    With IE
        .Navigate "http://re.jrc.ec.europa.eu/pvgis/apps4/pvest.php"
        .Visible = False 'false will not work correctly, unable to get to the popup

        Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        With .document
            .getElementsByname("address")(0).Value = "nitra"

            Set htmlColl = .getElementsBytagname("input")
            For Each htmlInput In htmlColl
                If Trim(htmlInput.Type) = "submit" And htmlInput.Value = "Search" Then
                    htmlInput.Click 'set location
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next htmlInput

            Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
            'set options (among others)
            .getElementsByname("outputchoicebuttons")(0).Click

            Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
            '! Blocked by automatic popups (enabled by hand for now)
            .getElementsByname("PVchoicesubmit")(0).Click 'click for the Popup window with data

            Debug.Print shellWins.Count 'with visible = 2, with hidden = 1

        End With '.document
    End With 'IE

        'check all opened windows and find the one with PV output
        For Each shlWindow In shellWins  
'...code to process the data  
End Sub
```

Comment: The form you're submitting will open a new window because its "target" attribute is set to "output".  If you set the target to "_self" before submitting, then it will open in the same window instead of a new one.

Comment: @TimWilliams This looks very promising. Thank you very much! I will test it tomorrow. I still don't know how to manipulate a hidden popup, but this workaround will do very well.

Comment: @TimWilliams. It works, but now I get a "dummy window". In the source code of the page, i found `var newwindow = window.open('dummy.html','output','height=700,width=550,toolbar=no,scrollbars=yes,resizable');`. It looks like some script. **How can I disable this? I don't want that popup at all.** I don't know how to find this code in HTML using VBA. Don't know where to look.